# Android emulator wont open in VS Code

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I cant get my Android Emulator to open in VS Code. It works in Android studio, I opened it and made sure it wasn't running there. I changed the windows path in the emulator extension to the location of my device, and then I get this error message the following error message.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5pb4.png)

Comment: path doesn't correct, reinstall emulator.